# QGIS - Scale bar segments

Tags: qgis, scale, scale-bar

Is it possible to divide a QGIS scale bar into different sized segments as you can in MapInfo (as with example given).

Or is it possible to select different style of scale bars in QGIS?

If it's not already obvious I'm normally a MapInfo user.

[image]

Comment: I was a MapInfo user too! It might take some time to get used to the QGIS workflow, but I find it to be much easier and full of features compared to MapInfo. Welcome to QGIS!

Answer (score 5):

You can have 2 sizes of segments, one to the left of 0 and one to the right. Although the full size of the left segment is one unit of the right, but can be subdivided however you want.

[image]

Comment: Can you have scalebars that don't have multiple numbers at each segment? ie Only one at the very beginning of the scale bar and one at the end?

Comment: Only if you have just 1 segment, like in your example.